# How to make my PC become an "psudo/fake" external display for android phone via USB ports (without using any USB to HDMI dongles)

Tags: linux, windows, usb, hdmi, android

I want my Android phone to recognize my PC as its external display (psuedo/fake or virtual displays) via USB connection (USB-C - USB-A cable or TCP connection) without using any USB to HDMI dongles or wifi display like miracast either.

I think I need to find or write the app/software or driver on PC side which have USB protocol like any real USB-C to HDMI display to communicate with the phone. Do you have any suggestion or guidelines?

Thanks,

Comment: You won't be able to achieve what you want without at least wireless streaming your display which of course, requires Miracast.  If you can't use USB to HDMI dongles, then even if you were to write an application that does what you describe you wouldn't be able to connect your phone to your PC.

Comment: USB-C DisplayPort Alt Mode (HDMI Alt Mode isn’t really used) cannot just be “implemented”. It _is_ DisplayPort, electronically. Not USB.

Comment: Reposted on [Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/252474/44325) and [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/87533/520)

Comment: @Loc, please dont multi-post

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is cross-posted on multiple sites, as mentioned in earlier comments.